# How to return specific row number of a Hierachial query - Oracle

Tags: oracle, hierarchy, recursive

I have this query that works as expected. Within Oracle SQL Developer it returns ~19,500 rows.  Unfortunately our current application limits our result to 10,000.  I know I will need to run this query multiple times and merge the resultsets. But I need to be able to limit query results in blocks of 10,000.

Adding a Where clause before the Start statement only works for the first execution:

`Where RowNum Between 1 and 10001` works as expected.

`Where RowNum Between 10001 and 20001` returns no rows.

Based on my testing, limiting by Level will not work due to the number of number of children within each level.

Thanks for all your help!

```
Select WFS.WORKFLOWSTEPID

, WFS.STEPTYPE

, WFS.SUBWORKFLOWBASEID

, WFS.SUBWORKFLOWID

, WFS.Sequence

, WFS.WORKFLOWSTEPNAME

, WFS.Sequence ParentSEQ

, WFB.WorkflowBaseID

, WFB.WORKFLOWNAME

, WFS.WORKFLOWID

, Level

from WorkflowBase WFB

Inner Join Workflow WF on WFB.REVOFRCDID = WF.Workflowid

Inner Join WorkflowStep WFS on WF.WORKFLOWID = WFS.WorkflowID

Start With WFS.WORKFLOWID =  '48810e80000001ca' 

Connect by Prior WFS.SubWorkflowBaseID = WFB.WorkflowBaseID

Order Siblings by ParentSeq, Sequence
```

Comment: If you are on Oracle 12c you can work with `OFFSET 10000 FETCH NEXT 10000`

https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/row-limiting-clause-for-top-n-queries-12cr1

Answer (score 1):

See this article from Oracle why the rownum approach won't work:
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/pseudocolumns009.htm

See this article on StackOverflow for the solution:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13351318/table-rownum-returns-0-records-if-rownum-is-tested-for-value-greater-than-100

Edit (for those who don't like reading):
- you want to do something like this

```
select count(*)
from (select rownum r
        from some_table
        order by r)
where r>=101 
and rownum <= 400;
```